# Azure AD - Retrieve custom attributes specific to application for a particular user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have several applications that I connect to via Azure AD and I want to be able to retrieve custom attributes specific to each application for a particular user.

For example: user 1 connects to application 1 and retrieves:

```
SqlDatabaseName: "BddName",
SqlDataBaseIpAdress: "0.0.0.0"
```

User 1 connects to application 2 and retrieves:

```
MotherBoardBrand: "MSI",
CPUBrand: "Intel"
```

Is it possible to feed the JWT token retrieved during connection with this information? If yes, how ?

Otherwise what would be the best way to proceed?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

John

Comment: To increase the possibility of getting an accurate answer you may want to expand on what type of applications you're referring to, and how they are integrated with Azure AD.  Ie. Are they web apps / app services, bespoke with custom AAD integration.  You should also clarify if these apps have registrations in AAD, as well as what language your applications are developed in because you may then get some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your applications possess registrations in AAD (they have their own identity), you will be able to grant permissions to them to read all user attributes. For typical auth flows (user and app reside in same directory), granting the App the `User.Read` permission should allow it access to read all attributes of the user. For a B2C authentication flow The `IdentityUserFlow.Read.All` permission should do it.

As for how you would read them in code, that depends on what language your apps are written in.

EDIT: And to answer your final question, no, the JWT will never contain any attributes of the user.